# Stream OpenCV Video Stream in HTML webpage Django Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using Django Framework.
Can anyone advise how should I modify the views.py to enable Video Stream at HTML webpage ?
Can anyone advise how to write the HTML webpage ?

Views.py

def camera(request):

```
id = 0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

while id == 0:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for obj in decodedObjects:
        #print("Data", obj.data)
        id = str(obj.data)

        id = id[2:-1]
        print(type(id))
        print(id)
        cv2.putText(frame, str(obj.data), (50, 50), font, 2,
                    (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if id != 0:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return redirect('product_detail', id)
        

return render(request, 'infos/index.html')
```

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution?

Comment: @Gaurav, do you have the solutions ?

Comment: I was already using Django Channels, so I sent my image via Web Sockets. I  converted my image to string and sent it to JS, decode and use. You can also use JSON for data transfer.